# Four divs side by side responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with side by side div. I made them to be responsive but I don't know how to show for example on 782px box one and two up and box three and four down, and on 480px i want them to be 100% one below another. Anyone can help?

HTML:

```
<div class="about-section" id="about">
<h3>Our Services</h3>
<div class="box" id="firstBox">
    <div class="top">
        <h2>Fully Responsive</h2>
        <img src="images/design-icon.png" alt="Icon for responsive design" />
        <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div><!-- end top !-->
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div><!-- end bottom !-->
</div><!-- end box-one !-->
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
        <h2>Graphic Design</h2>
        <img src="images/graphic-icon.png" alt="Icon for graphic design" />
        <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div><!-- end top !-->
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div><!-- end bottom !-->
</div><!-- end box-two !-->
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
        <h2>Programming</h2>
        <img src="images/programming-icon.png" alt="Icon for programming" />
        <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div><!-- end top !-->
        <div class="bottom">
    <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div><!-- end bottom !-->
</div><!-- end box-three !-->
<div class="box">
    <div class="top">
        <h2>Photography</h2>
        <img src="images/photography-icon.png" alt="Icon for photography" />
        <p>Voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium sprea totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div><!-- end top !-->
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href="#">Learn more</a>
    </div><!-- end bottom !-->
</div><!-- end box-four !-->
```

CSS:

```
.about-section {
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.about-section h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    margin: 90px 0 60px 0;
}
.box {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 22%;
    max-width: 275px;
    height: 275px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 4%;
}

#firstBox {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.top {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.top h2 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
.top img {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
.top p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999797;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
.bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #398db8;
    text-align: center;
}
.bottom a {
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
}
.bottom a:hover {
    color: #333;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
    .box {
    width: 90%;
    height: 275px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    }

    #firstBox {
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use media queries. I would start with something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 782px) {
 .box{
 width: 50%;
}

.box3{
margin-left: 0;
}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .box{
 width: 100%;    
}
}
```

Pasting the code in ruined the formatting, but this is essentially what you need to get you started. You'll need to adjust other styles in the media queries, but this will detect your screen width and adjust the boxes based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media query for this you can add this in yuour css as a base and try

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)   {

 .box {
  float:left;
  width:95%;
  margin:2%;
  height:auto;
  min-height:150px; 
  border:solid 1px #454545;
 }
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 483px) and  (max-width : 782px)   {

.box {
float:left;
width:42%;
margin:2%;
height:auto;
min-height:150px;   
border:solid 1px #454545;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width : 783px)    {

 .box {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  margin:2%;
  height:auto;
  min-height:150px; 
  border:solid 1px #454545;
 }
}
```